# Behavior of circular imports in Python3.7.6

Tags: python-3.7

I know it’s a captious question, but I need to know how this works (I am using Python 3.7.6):
I have intentionally included a circular loop.
What I need to know is:
1. Why is it looping only twice and then stops execution?
2. Why if `y=1` is alternatively placed AFTER the `import` statement in `app.py` an error(*) is thrown?

```
├── app
│   ├── another.py
│   └── app.py
└── main.py
```

**main.py**:

```
from app.app import y
from app.another import *
print("at main.py printing y: ", y)
print("at main.py printing z: ", z)
x = 1
```

**app.py**:

```
y = 1
from main import *
print("at app.py printing z: ", z)
print("at app.py printing x: ", x)
```

**another.py**:

```
z = 3
```

The output is:

```
at main.py printing y:  1
at main.py printing z:  3
at app.py printing z:  3
at app.py printing x:  1
at main.py printing y:  1
at main.py printing z:  3
```

**error**: (when `y=1` placed after imports)

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'y' from 'app.app'
```